# Rewriting urls with htaccess and PHP

Tags: php

Original Link of my PHP page is `page.php?id=70` i want to rewrite it to `page`
please give me a suggestion, this is code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteRule   ^[a-zA-Z]+/?$  page.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. Thanks... Your current htaccess will rewrite f.e. domain.com/my_page to domain.com/?id=my_page; but I guess you want to have there ID.

Comment: You want to redirect from `/page.php?id=70` to `/page`?

Comment: yes I want to redirect from /page.php?id=70 to /page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works - I just tested it.**

> `RewriteRule ^page/$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

After this change in php file where is your link like:

```
<a href="<?=HTTP_PATH?>/page/">Your text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
> RewriteRule   ^/page.php?id=([0-9]+)$  /page  [L]
> ```

OR if you want redirect only from id=70, than:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
> RewriteRule   ^/page.php?id=70$  /page  [L]
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way is always the best, even people can access your urls directly by typing them, in your case I'll use:

```
  RewriteRule    ^page/([0-9]+)/?$    page.php?id=$1
```

This will give you urls in this format: mydomain.com/page/23/

Cheers

Comment: @Sanjay you want to redirect page.php?id=70 to page-70 or page/70/ be more specific.