# How to redirect page with query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect

```
whorus.php?lang=en&id=99
```

into

```
about.php?lang=en&id=99
```

- I want to keep the same query string [QSA]
- I want to change the page ["whorus" -> "about"]

what should I use? Redirect? RewriteRule

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values#answer-901144)

Comment: I need htaccess solution, not jquery

Comment: See the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653795/rewriting-urls-with-htaccess-and-php/19653987#19653987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an internal rewrite then following will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^whorus\.php$ /about.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

If you want an external redirect (change the URL in the browser) then following will work with `R` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^whorus\.php$ /about.php [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: I tried this, but when I try to browse [http://www.mySite.com/whorus.php?language=_en] is translated into [http://www.mySite.com/home/mySite/public_html/about.php?language=_en] => not found, because of the additional [home/mySite/public_html] what is missing?

Comment: OK edited, can you try now.

Answer (score 0):

The query string should remain with something like this. This will perform a permanent 301 redirect.

```
RewriteRule whorus.php http://www.newsite.com/about.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: should I also add [qsa] ? as [L,R=301, QSA]